# Build failed when build the android_core in rosjava

Tags: android-core, rosjava, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,
I'm new in this ROS and ROSjava world. I was installing the android_core following the documentation, http://docs.rosjava.googlecode.com/hg/android_core/html/building.html, but when I want to build debug APKs for all android_core packages (./gradlew debug), I'm getting the next error:

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':android_acm_serial:updateProject'.

> A problem occurred starting command 'android'.

I'm in the right folder and I have installed the android_core, android SDK and Apache Ant.

Any ideas? Anyone is getting the same error?
Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33511/build-failed-when-build-the-android_core-in-rosjava/) by [santidoo](https://answers.ros.org/users/2338/santidoo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2012-05-08

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Finally I could solve that problem. The steps that I followed are the next, I hope it help:

1. Clear the maven cache:
   $ rm -rf ~/.m2/repository/ros
2. Delete the rosjava folder (if already installed) and create it again:
   $ rm -r Workspace
      $ mkdir -p Workspace
3. Install rosjava:
   $ rosinstall ~/Workspace https://kforge.ros.org/appmanandroid/hg/raw-file/tip/appman.rosinstall
4. Install android_core:
   $ cd ~/Workspace
      $ rosws merge http://android.rosjava.googlecode.com/hg/.rosinstall
   $ rosws update
5. Build rosjava_core:
   $ roscd rosjava_core
      $ ./gradlew install
   -- optionals
   $ ./gradlew docs
     $ ./gradlew test
   $ ./gradlew eclipse
6. Install google:
   $ roscd google
      $ ./gradlew install
7. Install android_core:
   $ roscd android_core
      $ ./gradlew debug

---

Originally posted by [santidoo](https://answers.ros.org/users/2338/santidoo/) with karma: 46 on 2012-05-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have the same issue and do have the path set, so that
android
launches the SDK managment tool from the directory called out in the error.  However, still get this message:

[ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "android" (in directory "/home/dbarry/rosAndroid/android_core/android_acm_serial"): java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
14:10:07.223 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.process.internal.ExecHandleRunner.run(ExecHandleRunner.java:69)
14:10:07.224 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    ... 1 more
14:10:07.224 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory

In fact, even copying the executable file Android into the directory does not help much-- still get an error at the same spot:

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':android_acm_serial:updateProject'.

> A problem occurred starting command 'android'.

but with a different debug:

[org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild] The daemon has finished executing the build.
14:16:45.529 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ReturnResult] Daemon is dispatching the build result: DaemonCommandResult[type=CommandFailure, value=org.gradle.launcher.exec.ReportedException: org.gradle.api.internal.LocationAwareException: Execution failed for task ':android_acm_serial:updateProject'.]
14:16:45.737 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClientInputForwarder] input forwarder stop requested
14:16:45.739 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClientInputForwarder] Dispatching close input message: CloseI

---

Originally posted by [dan](https://answers.ros.org/users/144/dan/) with karma: 875 on 2012-05-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1